# how installation full SDK on linux ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu

I am new user Linux Ubuntu and I want to install Android SDK. I see website https://developer.android.com/studio/ but I can't find full SDK and when I wanna download from the android studio I have these problems:

[image]

And also I have this problem: [Problem with Android SDK of Android Studio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948754/problem-with-adroid-sdk-of-android-studio).

Anybody can help me this?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to install Android Studio?

Comment: no, install SDK Required for work android studio!

Comment: Didn't Android studio give you a wizard to download sdk on first lunch?

Comment: no! https://askubuntu.com/questions/948754/problem-with-adroid-sdk-of-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

From your ***Screenshot*** tap on Edit and select some location for Android SDK to be installed. If there will be no SDK on that location than Studio will download it for you.